# Cannot see Tensorflow logs in google colab notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I was playing around with tensorflow apis on google colab virtual notebook. I want to see device mapping of my colab virtual machine.

As mentioned on tensorflow developer guide, I can set the flag (log_device_placement=True) to enable logging. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu

Below is my code running on colab notebook -

```
import tensorflow as tf
# Creates a graph.
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
c = tf.matmul(a, b)

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print(sess.run(c))
```

But it doesn't seems to work on colab notebook. However it is working with local jupyter notebook terminal console.

Any idea how to enable logging on google colab platform ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a TensorFlow issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3047

Or, a jupyter issue: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1230

Here's a work-around using a third-party library:

```
!pip install wurlitzer

import tensorflow as tf
# Creates a graph.
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
c = tf.matmul(a, b)

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))

# Runs the op.
from wurlitzer import pipes

with pipes() as (out, err):
  print(sess.run(c))

print (out.read())
```

Full notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Z5FVCD_z8EMmyd31PsjQffQV_K7dDLfj

Comment: Thanks @bob-smith , wurlitzer works like a charm. I have one more query. Even though I selected TPU as a runtime in colab, TF session jobs are still running on CPU as per the logs. What extra config parameter should I pass to tf session to make it run these jobs on TPU ?

Comment: Please use distinct questions for distinct issues. Thanks!